# Cannot overfit on the IRIS dataset

Tags: overfitting

I am playing with the IRIS dataset and want to see underfitting and overfitting in action. I am using a multilayer perceptron ([2 layers](https://gist.github.com/ychervonyi/d7d119492e09e2b89bcdae98bdb8eb6a)).

It is pretty easy to underfit (see the plot below), but I am having problems with overfitting. The dataset capacity is 600 (# of samples (150) times # of features (4)), so I should be able to overfit using a network with a capacity bigger than that. I am trying to use a multilayer perceptron with a total # of parameters of ~32000, but overfitting does not happen. What is going on? Thank you!

[image: Val and train]

[image: Val only]

[image]

If I make a learning rate smaller everything get smoother, but still no overfitting.

[image]

Comment: Could you repost the plot, excluding the training lines?

Comment: For this type of analysis, you should be comparing a proper loss function like cross-entropy. Accuracy is necessarily limited to the set from 0 to 1 in fractions of $1/n$, so it will conceal considerable information about what's going on.

Comment: @jbowman Sure, I added another plot.

Comment: Notice how, when you get out to epochs 50+, the purple line seems to give the poorest average result, followed by the turquoise (or whatever color that is) line, then it looks like the red is the next worst, which leaves the green as the best.  @Sycorax is exactly correct, you should be using a proper loss function, but even with this accuracy measure you can, in an informal way, see a pattern there.

Comment: @jbowman But those are just some fluctuations, in the end all lines (except the blue one) are pretty close to each other.

Comment: @Sycorax The same thing happens when I plot the loss function. I am adding the plot.

Comment: The fact that the value of your loss changes so discretely makes me think that different data points are entering and exiting your test set at different epochs.  A proper loss functions generally changes somewhat smoothly over different epochs.  Any idea what is going on there?

Comment: @MatthewDrury Good point, but I split the data into the train and test sets at the very beginning (it happens only once). Maybe the loss changes are discrete because the dataset is pretty small?

Comment: I would expect that with accuracy, since the datapoints classification status changes discretely, but your model loss should be log-loss, which is based on probabilities.

Comment: @MatthewDrury If I make a learning rate smaller, loss curves get smoother.

Comment: Ahhh, ok then. That clears it up.

Answer (score 4):

Are you measuring training set performance there? It is per definition impossible to see overfit in the training set performance (underfit you would see).

Also, it is in theory absolutely possible to have a data-set on which you cannot overfit. The classes could be so well separated that even a horribly overfitting algorithm like 1NN always finds a one nearest neighbor that is of the same class.

With the iris data-set. Setosa is very easy to separate from the other two, but virginica and versicolor have some overlap so that you should see decreasing test-set performance as you overfit. My best guess is that you are measuring training set performance.

Comment: Ofc I measure both training and testing performances, dashed lines - accuracy on training set. I added the label. But I like the second thought though.